# Resizing Twitter Bootstrap Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have this (using TB):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2"></div>
      <div class="span8"></div>
      <div class="span2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need the first `.span2` to be a bit wider. It looks like the `.span8` has some sort of margin/padding that represents the gutter. If I could reduce that a bit, then the first `.span2` would get wider, I think.

I can't seem to find the appropriate selector and property to set. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you not just change it to be a span3 then change the next one to be a span7? Then within the span3 place another custom sized DIV that contains whatever the element you want to place in there is?

Comment: No. I really just need span2 -- and just a bit of the gutter after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the span width it will mess up the widths of all the other spans. Your best bet would be to build a custom bootstrap css file with a different grid size.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: I don't want to affect all the grid sizes. Just that one span2 on one page of my site.

Comment: I had that problem, you can try putting a span on your container, not sure though, I hate modifying spans on bootstrap

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There are gutters defined between columns, right? I can't find that.